# PVC pipe projector screen frame 18x10. How to support top heavy?

Tags: pipe, pvc, frame, projector

I built a frame for my projector screen outta PVC Pipe. It's roughly 18 feet long and 10 feet high. I did 2 5 foot sections vertically and 3 6 foot sections horizontally. I have a base at each section of 2 feet on each side.  Basically a tic tac toe board.

Problem is it's a little top heavy.  Right now I have staked it In the ground to control it. But that's a temporary fix. Is there any kind of PVC brace support that I could put 2 feet on each side of the T connection to make sure it holds up?

Any idea are welcome

Comment: You can see what you built. We have little idea beyond the terse bit of information that you doled out. Join the big leagues and at least provide some pictures. Also missing is important information regarding the size and type of PVC pipe used. In addition we have no idea of what type of couplers and fittings you used. And lastly you gave no clue how you are likely to want to mount this thing.

Answer (score 1):

> **Any idea are welcome**

- fill bottom tube(s) with lead shot or sand.
- buy some extra tee and 45 degree joints and make triangular braces.